# How to deploy a React + Express + Flask app on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a web application to deploy that has react as the frontend, express and flask as the backend services. Currently, I am running a EC2 instance and put these on but I would also like to deploy these services with CI/CD. I've looked into ElasticBeanstalk but I'm not sure how I can deploy both express and flask on the same instance. Shall I consider docker in this case?

Comment: how do you deploy it outside of AWS? If you run inside EC2, you are just running a VM that is similar to a Linux server box. Docker has no special benefit unless you are already using it and have everything to go. In which case Docker on EC2 is possible but overall not different from Docker elsewhere. For that you can also look into ECS. As for Beanstalk, if your system is simple, try it and see if it works for your configuration.

Comment: So I have a React App and it will call APIs from the Express backend. But some Express APIs will need to call APIs from the Flask backend. What is the best way to have all these up on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/

You have to launch 3 different EC2 instances and install CodeDeploy agent on each. Make sure you have a different repository for your React, Express and Flask app.

Comment: If I launched three different instances, what should I do so that when my react frontend wants to call api from localhost, it actually points to the other instance.